# 3d application for web and raspberry pi

Tags: web, 3d, raspberry-pi, blender

I want to build an application where the user can switch off and on the lights in a 3d scene (building and lights modeled in blender). It should work both for a web browser and for raspberry pi (model B, B+), local.

For the web I normally use xdom, but this does not work for the raspberry, because there is no WebGL.

Is there a technology I can use that works for both?

Comment: I dont know if you can switch to Java. It works fine on RPi......

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check out the Emscripten project. Emscripten basically compiles C/C++ code into JavaScript so you can run your code in a web browser. Unfortunately I have never used it, but I found some cases where they used OpenGL ES code which was then "compiled" into WebGL.

Here's the documentation page for the OpenGL support in Emscripten:
https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/multimedia_and_graphics/OpenGL-support.html

And below you can find an example of the glxgears compiled with Emscripten:
http://ehsanakhgari.org/blog/2012-01-25/porting-opengl-application-web

Hope this helps, cheers